# Populate Json data in two td per tr

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Here is my code to retrieve data from webmethod. Function gets 10 random raffle numbers, so it must pe populated in a table with two td per row. i have used odd even logic but i cant solve it. I hope someone can help me with this.

```
 function GetTopTenStubs() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ConsolationRaffle.aspx/GetTopTenStubs",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    var parsed = $.parseJSON(response.d);
                    var cam;

                    var cnt = 1;
                    $.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {

                        //console.log(cnt + ' - ' + jsondata.Stubs);


                        if (parseInt(cnt) % 2 === 0) {
                            console.log(cnt + ' - ' + jsondata.Stubs + ' Even');

                             cam += '<tr class="trstyle"><td>' + jsondata.Stubs + '</td>';
                        }


                        if (parseInt(cnt) % 2 == 1) {
                            console.log(cnt + ' - ' + jsondata.Stubs + ' Odd');
                             cam += '<td>' + jsondata.Stubs + '</td>';
                            cam += '</tr>';
                        }
                        cnt++;
                         $('#fivecamera').append(cam);
                    });

                }
            });
```

The result of this process must look like this.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;    
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr >
   <th colspan="2">Consolation Winners</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555</td>
    <td>551</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>109</td>
    <td>854</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>898</td>
    <td>574</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>155</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>006</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why u used odd even logic?

Comment: what you want to achieve is unclear. please explain more.

Comment: Start count from 0. var cnt = 0;

Comment: i figure it out like this.

Comment: var parsed = $.parseJSON(response.d);
 var cam = '';
 var cnt = 1;
$.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {
cam += '<td>' + jsondata.Stubs + '</td>';
 if (cnt % 2 === 0) {
 $('#fivecamera').append('<tr class="trstyle">' + cam + '</tr>');
cam = '';
 }
if ( cnt % 2 > 0 && parsed.length == cnt) {
$('#fivecamera').append('<tr class="trstyle">' + cam + '<td></td></tr>');
}
cnt++;

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (response) {
                    var parsed = $.parseJSON(response.d);
                    var cam;

                    var cnt = 0;
                     $.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {

                       if(cnt == 0){
                            cam += '<tr class="trstyle">';
                        } 
                       if(cnt >=0 && cnt <2) {
                            cam += '<td>' + jsondata.Stubs + '</td>';
                        } 
                       if(cnt == 2) {
                            cam += '</tr>'; 
                            cnt = 0;  
                        }else{
                         cnt++;
                        }


                    });
                    $('#fivecamera').append(cam); 

                }
```

You can start with count 0 and increment it up to 2 and again make it 0. Try use above code. I have not tested it but it should give you a clear idea. Let me know if it works or not.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi your code works but count 3,6,9 will not add up in the table. i figure out some way.

Comment: i figure it out

Comment: var parsed = $.parseJSON(response.d); var cam = ''; var cnt = 1; $.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) { cam += '<td>' + jsondata.Stubs + '</td>'; if (cnt % 2 === 0) { $('#fivecamera').append('<tr class="trstyle">' + cam + '</tr>'); cam = ''; } if ( cnt % 2 > 0 && parsed.length == cnt) { $('#fivecamera').append('<tr class="trstyle">' + cam + '<td></td></tr>'); } cnt++

Answer (score 0):

You are starting from count 1. Following condition will satisfy and  will be added in place of

```
parseInt(cnt) % 2 == 1
```

Start from var cnt = 0;